# SSH доступ по ключу [закрыт]

Tags: ssh, linux

Под рутом авторизуется по ключу. Под обычным юзером требует пароль несмотря на наличие ключа в /home/user/.ssh/authorized_keys.
Выдержка из /etc/ssh/sshd_config на сервере:
    RSAAuthenticattion yes
    PubkeyAuthentication yes
    AuthorizedKeysFile  .ssh/authorized_keys
    PasswordAuthentication no
Подскажите в чем может быть проблема? Где копать?

Comment: я на всякий случай спрошу: а с паролем пускает?

Comment: с паролем пускает.

Comment: мне кажется, что @Anton Shevtsov задал наводящий на решение проблемы вопрос, наверное нужно это отметить )

Answer (score 1):

Какие права на `~/.ssh и ~/.ssh/authorized_keys` ? И ввод `ssh -vv user@server` сюда

Comment: ~/.ssh 700 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys 600.вывод здесь: http://yadi.sk/d/GwTyObJL8dQZi

Comment: вывод 142 байт? И бросьте вы использовать окуппационный яндекс.диск - pastebin.com вот сюда все

Comment: пожалуйста http://pastebin.com/D7gkb8wR

Comment: в /var/log/auth или /var/log/secure что по этому поводу пишет ? я так думаю вы просто ключ неправильно вставили.

Comment: /var/log/auth.logSep  4 01:52:38 foxconn gnome-keyring-daemon[1824]: unsupported key algorithm in certificate: 1.2.840.10045.2.1

Comment: Remote: Ignored authorized keys: bad ownership or modes for directory /home/user

Comment: Всем спасибо! Как оказалось был косяк с правами на /home/user